# Passing value to a function argument

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I have someone's code which sets the name of a new Object.

```
function setName(human) { 
    human.name = "Nicholas";
    human = new Object();
    human.name = "Greg";
};

var newPerson = new Object(); 
setName(newPerson); 
console.log(newPerson.name);
```

I want to use the value of the property 'name' of the person object.

I was expecting the value to be 'Greg' but I am getting 'Nicholas'.

This is my understanding: 'human' is a pointer to an Object. When the function is called, another pointer to the same Object would be created by the name of newPerson.

The 'name' property of the newPerson Object would be set to 'Nicholas'. Then, another newPerson object is created in the second line of the function. Hence, the first instance should be destroyed. Then, the 'name' property of this new Object would be set to 'Greg'. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of variables with object values as *handles* to these objects.

```
var newPerson = new Object();
```

You created a new object and a handle to it called `newPerson`.

```
setName(newPerson);

function setName(human) {
```

When `setName` is called, `newPerson` is copied into `human`. So now you have two handles that refer to the same object. It so happens that both of them are actually accessible inside the function, but this doesn't really matter to the discussion.

```
    human.name = "Nicholas";
```

The object referred to by `human` has a new name. Since `human` and `newPerson` are still handles to the same object, `newPerson.name` has now changed as well.

```
    human = new Object();
```

Now the handles diverge. `newPerson` still continues to be a handle to Nicholas, but `human` becomes a handle to the new object.

```
    human.name = "Greg";
```

And this new object's name is Greg. This does not affect Nicholas in any way.

```
};

console.log(newPerson.name);
```

`newPerson` is still a handle to Nicholas.

Comment: Ohh, I see now! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

**human** is local variable for function.

> human = new Object();

After this line you have new object for local variable **human** but not for that variable which you sent to function as argument

It means that you sent arguments to function by value.

For example in C# you can use keywork **ref** which will make funciton working as you expected.